# Substring is getting nullpointer exception

Tags: apex, map, string, null-pointer

I have a map of contacts. Need to print substring of title. but it errors out, when title is null :

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

```
public class k {
    public Map<id,Contact> getcc(){
        Map<id,Contact> cc=new Map<id,Contact>([select Id,title,name from Contact ]);
        system.debug('++++++++++++'+cc.get('0039000001EkSEz').title.substring(0,1));
        return cc;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is ur requirement ? why r u querying all the contacts, if u jus need to get the title of only one contact ?

Comment: actually this code is a small testing part of web-service call, where i have to form a requestor string, and then send it to http req body , with each contact details. here i'm debugging with one contact, where title is null, and hence error occurs.

Comment: updated the code with  system.debug('++++++++++++'+ If(isNotBlank(cc.get('0039000001EkSEz')) ){ cc.get('0039000001EkSEz').title.substring(0,1)); but it errors out : unexpected token: 'If'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because *title* field of that contact is `null`. There are 2 options for you to solve it:

1. Check if title is not `null` before calling `substring` method
2. Surround this part with `try-catch`

---

In first case your code would look like:

```
public Map<id,Contact> getcc(){
    Map<id,Contact> cc=new Map<id,Contact>([select Id,title,name from Contact]);
    if (cc.get('0039000001EkSEz').title != null)
        System.debug('++++++++++++'+cc.get('0039000001EkSEz').title.substring(0,1));
    else
        System.debug('This contact has no title');
    return cc;
}
```

This will check whether *title* field of this contact is not `null`(has some value).

In second case your code would be:

```
public Map<id,Contact> getcc(){
    Map<id,Contact> cc=new Map<id,Contact>([select Id,title,name from Contact]);
    try {
        System.debug('++++++++++++'+cc.get('0039000001EkSEz').title.substring(0,1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('This contact has no title. Exception: ' + e + '\nAt line: ' + e.getLineNumber());
    }
    return cc;
}
```

This will try to print the substring of the *title* of your contact, but if the *title* is `null`, it will catch an *Exception*. In this case, code in your `catch` block will be executed.

I'd also recommend reading about *[Exception handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling)*

Answer (score 4):

I m still not clear on your overall requirement.. but based on your code, to resolve the error you have couple of options

query only the contact records which has values in the title field or

```
Map<id,Contact> cc=new Map<id,Contact>([select Id,title,name from Contact where title != null ]);
```

before applying the substring, check if title is not null

```
string titleStr = cc.get('0039000001EkSEz').title;
if(titleStr != null)
system.debug('++++++++++++'+titleStr.substring(0,1));
```

but i would suggest not to query the entire contacts.. use query filters to look for a subset of records based on your scenario.. and please don't hardcode any record id's in your code.